# $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz=5,\: R\geq R_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $p$ be a polyonimal of degree $5$, prove it exist $R_0>0$ such that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz=5,\: R\geq R_0$

---

**Any hint ?**

$\cdot$ The term $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ yelds for Cauchy integral formula, but I dont see how to set a function such that $f(z_0)=5$

$\cdot$  Aslo the depedence on the radius makes me think that I need big enought $R$ s.t some root is in the disc ? maybe use Residue ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: @Fred $p$ doesn't have poles, so I take big enough $R$ to contain all the roots and I assume  am done

Answer (score 1):

First note that for a polynomial, $p(x)$, with $n$ roots, $r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n$, then

$$\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{z-r_k}$$

This follows by applying the derivative product rule to $p(x)=a\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-r_k)$, and then dividing by $p(x)$ and canceling out terms.

You can now split your integral into pieces and use the residue theorem on each pole, assuming you choose $R$ sufficiently large to include all the zeros of $p(x)$.